# How to access list in Scala test case

Tags: scala

I have a test case as a list, and I want to access "Andorra" as input[0] and "04" as input[1] of the list for a parameter, but I am given the error value input of type (String, String) does not take type parameters. How do I properly access these strings and use them for my parameters?

```
  test("normal case") {
    val testCases = List {
      ("Andorra", "04") -> (Map("la massana" -> 7211), List("les escaldes"))

    }
    for ((input, (mapOut, listOut)) <- testCases) {
      var computedMap: collection.mutable.Map[String, Int] = PaleBlueDot.cityPopulations(countriesFile, citiesFilename, input[0], input[1])
      var computedList: List[String] = PaleBlueDot.aboveAverageCities(countriesFile, citiesFilename, input[0])
      assert(computedMap == mapOut, input + " -> " + computedMap)
      assert(computedList.sorted == listOut.sorted, input + " -> " + computedList)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just expand the match in the `for` statement to `((country, code), (mapOut, listOut)) <- testCases`. `country` will be `"Andorra"` and `code` will be `"04"`.

Comment: `input` is a `Tuple`. You can access values as input._1, input._2. BTW, you can also access tuple values as you have done with `(mapOut, listOut)`, ie instead of `input`, something like `(country, id)`

Comment: When I expanded the for loop to for ((country, code), (mapOut, listOut)) <- testCases, it created an error '<-' expected but ',' found. Also, what would I put in place of input for my assertions.

Comment: You meant this gives an error `for (((country, code), (mapOut, listOut)) <- testCases)`?